# Which Root CA still issues SHA-1 ssl certificates?

Tags: ssl, sha1, certificate-authority

Is there any CA that still issues SHA-1 certificates?
I need it for TR management to manage devices with base firmware that does not support sha256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imho, Public CA's will no longer issues SHA-1 certificates; they are bounded by the strict guidance of the Certificate Authority/Browser Forum to no longer issue new server certificates with SHA1 signature algorithm.

> 7.1.3. Algorithm Object Identifiers
>
> Effective 1 January 2016, CAs MUST NOT issue any new Subscriber
>   certificates or Subordinate CA certificates using the SHA‐1 hash
>   algorithm. CAs MAY continue to sign certificates to verify OCSP
>   responses using SHA1 until 1 January 2017. This Section 7.1.3 does not
>   apply to Root CA or CA cross certificates. CAs MAY continue to use
>   their existing SHA‐1 Root Certificates. SHA‐2 Subscriber certificates
>   SHOULD NOT chain up to a SHA‐1 Subordinate CA Certificate.

https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.3.7.pdf